# Why isn't my theme processing SASS?

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style, sass

It's my understanding that Wordpress now processes SASS files but for some reason mine don't work.

I'm trying to call it using `wp_enqueue_style` directly in `header.php` via the `head` tag:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_style('stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', $ver = false, $media = 'screen') ?>
```

Instead, the file gets called as a normal CSS doc.

I attempted to rename `style.css` to `style.scss` but then the file doesn't load at all, so I guess the sass pre-processor just isn't firing.

Comment: _It's my understanding that Wordpress now processes SASS files_ … why do you think it does?

Comment: @toscho https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/26137

Comment: I think that's only for a user's choice of colourscheme in the admin screens.

Comment: You're probably better to enqueue the styles using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook, too. Check the **User Contributed Notes » Using a Hook** section on [this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/).

Comment: @nipponese That was for preprocessing core files on the wordpress.org server. It happens _before_ WordPress is packed and distributed. That has no relevance for themes.

Answer (score 2):

@nipponese is right. WordPress doesn't process Sass for themes. That was just for core files on wordpress.org.